# Java code instrumentation using annotations

Tags: java, instrumentation

I've got a huge java project with tons of code. Let us assume it looks like:

```
fn1(int arg1){...}
fn2(int arg1,int arg2){...}
fn23(){...}
...
fn134(){...}
```

I want to log each invocation of functions using annotations:

```
@logme("arg1")
fn1(int arg1){...}
@logme("all args")
fn2(int arg1,int arg2){...}
fn23(){...}
...
fn134(){...}
```

and expect seeing

```
fn1(arg1=223)
fn1(arg1=213,arg2=46)
```

in my log files

Would you be so kind to propose me some tool?

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use AspectJ & any logging framework to handle this requirement, 
so you need to do the following:

1- create your annotation which take arguments as you may wish, or even take a string of undefined number of arguments, and process them like`'arg1=q,arg2=w,arg3=e'`

2- create an aspect with point cut on your new annotation like this

```
@Pointcut(value = "@annotation(loggableActivity)", argNames = "loggableActivity")
```

notice that argNames used here to send the annotation itself to the handler method, so you can get arguments from it like`'arg1=q,arg2=w,arg3=e'`, and process them

3- before proceeding the method call, log what ever you want about it, you can get almost all needed info from your arguments,

Annotation code looks like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LoggableActivity {
    String value();

    String args() default "";
}
```

point cut code looks like:

```
@Aspect
public class ActivityLogger {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("activity");

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(loggableActivity)", argNames = "loggableActivity")
    public void loggableUserActivity(LoggableActivity loggableActivity) {

    }

    @Around("loggableUserActivity(loggableActivity)")
    public Object doLoggingUserActivity(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
            LoggableActivity loggableActivity) throws Throwable {}
```

then inside `doLoggingUserActivity` you may use methods like

```
pjp.proceed(); proceed method call
pjp.getArgs(); gets method arguments
loggableActivity.args(); gets annotation argument as String
```

then use logger to log them

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for this purpose. Here you can find a short documentation how to define the appropriate [PointCuts](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/index.html)